# currentValue.indexOf is not a function at getValueForCheckbox in Formik

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, formik

I'm trying to build a group checkbox component with formik as in the photo
[table of checkbox group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsxaD.png)

My ***checkbox componet code*** is:

```
const CheckBox = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField({ ...props, type: "checkbox" });
  return (
    <>
      <label className="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" {...field} {...props} />
        {children}
      </label>
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <div className="text text-danger">{meta.error}</div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

and this is the ***implementation of checkbox group:***

```
                <thead className="thead-light">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    {data.periods
                      ? data.periods.map((time, index) => (
                          <th scope="col" key={index}>
                            {time[0]}
                          </th>
                        ))
                      : null}
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {data.day_of_week
                    ? data.day_of_week.map((day, index) => (
                        <tr key={index}>
                          <th scop="row">{day[1]}</th>
                          {data.periods
                            ? data.periods.map((time, index) => (
                                <td key={index}>
                                  <CheckBox
                                    name="acceptedTime"
                                    key={index}
                                    value={time[0]}
                                  />
                                </td>
                              ))
                            : null}
                        </tr>
                      ))
                    : null}
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

**When I click on each of these checkboxes I get the error `currentValue.indexOf is not a function`.**

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

We can't see your "data", which would be helpful, but in short, the library you are using for your form is expecting indexOf() to work on the value of the checkbox, but it is not.

Your code is written to suggest "data" has a day_of_week array and a periods array, and that the periods array *items* are themselves iterable (i.e. arrays, strings, etc.) with at least one value each. When you write the [0] in there, you are making a promise that it has at least one value. And the form library you are using is *also* expecting that the value will have an indexOf property, which it would automatically if it were a string or array.

I suspect that `time`, which is pointing at each item in your `periods` array, is undefined, or an empty array or string, or it is of some type where saying [0] on it doesn't make sense. And if it does make sense, whatever it has there (at time[0]) is probably undefined.

Comment: thank you for your response but my data is Contains
:day_of_week: 
0:  ["0", "Sat."]
1:  ["1", "Sun."]
2:  ["2", "Mon."]
3:  ["3", "Tue."]
4:  ["4", "Wed."]
5:  ["5", "Thu."]
6:  ["6", "Fri."]
---------------
periods:
0:  ["08:00-12:00", "08:00-12:00"]
1:  ["12:00-16:00", "12:00-16:00"]
2:  ["16:00-20:00", "16:00-20:00"]

Comment: Is your periods property *always* that, i.e. from start to finish? It's never loading or any other value?

Comment: Yes, almost always. The second index of this presentation( time[1] ) is going to be in another language